# Why the relational table in the database formed during oneToMany Mapping have no records in it?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, orm, one-to-many

I have created a Spring boot project based on **OneToMany Mapping**. I created two entities, **Customer and Branch** where one branch can have many customers. It's a **bi-directional mapping** but I **don't want to use 'mappedBy'** and hence I am getting one extra table in the database. The two tables Customer and Branch have records in them but the relational table created has no records in it. **How to get those records?**

Following are the Customer.java and Branch.java entities.

```
    package com.shiva.enterprises.banking.repositories;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Range;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Entity
@Table(name="BANK_CUSTOMER")
@Getter @Setter
public class Customer {

    @Column(name="FIRST_NAME", length = 50)     
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="LAST_NAME", length = 50)
    private String lastName;

    @Id
    @Range(min = 10000, max = 99999, message = "CIF Number must be 5-digit number.")
    @Column(name="CIF_NO", length = 5)      
    private int cifNo;

    @Column(name="REGISTERED_DATE")
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MMM/yyyy")
    private LocalDateTime registeredDate;

    @Column(name="ACCOUNT_BALANCE")
    private long balance;

    @Column(name="STATUS")
    private String status;

    @Range(min = 10000000, max = 99999999, message = "Account number must be 8-digit number.")  
    @Column(name="ACCOUNT_NO", length = 8)                 
    private long accNo;

    //Adding address
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="ADDRESS_ID")   
    private Address address;

    //Adding Branch
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="BRANCH_CODE")
    private Branch branch;

}
```

Following is the Branch.java code.

```
package com.shiva.enterprises.banking.repositories;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Range;

import java.util.ArrayList;

@Getter @Setter
@Entity
@Table(name="BANK_BRANCH")
public class Branch {

    @Id
    @Column(name="BRANCH_NO")
    @Range(min=10000, max=99999, message = "Please enter valid branch number.")
    private int branchNo;

    @Column(name="BRANCH_NAME")
    private String branchName;

    @Column(name="BRANCH_ADDRESS")
    private String branchAddress;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private ArrayList<Customer> customers;

}
```

Comment: why you don't want to use mappedBy cause this is your problem

Comment: Actually, I just want to learn why is it not populating it.